# How could I plot the sum of different functions evalued with different parameters contained in a file with Gnuplot?

Tags: signals, gnuplot

I do have a file with the peak position of a signal.
For each peak I need to broad the signal with a known function.
Basically I need to plot F(x)= Sum(f(x,a)) over different "a" values which are store in a file.

I can plot easily one function at the time, but not all of them together:

plot "data" u 1:f(($2))

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood completely your problem, so this might just be an hint.

Imagine you have a file `data.dat` like this:

```
0.2
2.2
3.4
2.4
1.5
7.6
7.1
2.0
```

a function like this:

```
f(x,a)=x*a
```

can be plotted using the `a` values from `data.dat` like this:

```
data=system("cat data.dat")
plot for [i=0:words(data)] f(x,real(word(data,i))) title word(data,i)
```

and you'll get this kind of graph:

[image]

To plot the sum, you can use the `sum` keyword (more info with `help sum`):

```
plot sum [i=0:words(data)] f(x,real(word(data,i)))
```

or

```
plot "+" u 1:(sum [i=0:words(data)] f($1,real(word(data,i))))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you very much. Many interesting commands, unfortunately in this way you plot
     f_i(x) for the i number of data. The idea was to plot F(x) = \sum_i f_i(x).

I hope the latex syntax is clear .